# Error: Reducer "getSelectedItem" returned undefined during initialization

Tags: reactjs, redux

I had some hard times the last days having Redux working with my React App. I needed to have a component "Item" to render() based on the current selectedItemId from another ItemSelector component. Basically, I have this working at this point :

ItemSelector.js :

```
[...]
import { createStore, bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { selectItem } from "../reducers"

const store = createStore(selectItem)

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  selectItem: bindActionCreators(selectItem, dispatch)
})

class ItemSelector extends React.Component {
    render() {
        [...]
        this.props.selectItem(ItemId)
        [...]
    }
}

export default connect(() => ({}), mapDispatchToProps)(ItemSelector)
```

Item.js :

```
[...]
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getSelectedItem } from '../reducers'

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        itemId: getSelectedItem(state)
    }
}

class Item extends React.Component {
    render() {
        [...]
        {this.props.itemId}
        [...]
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Item)
```

reducers/index.js

```
const SELECT_ITEM = "SELECT_ITEM"

export const selectItem = (itemId) => {
  return {
    type: SELECT_ITEM,
    itemId
  }
}

export const getSelectedItem = (state) => {
  return state
}

export default (state = 'DEFAULT_ITEM', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT_ITEM:
      return action.itemId
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Now, I would like to add more reducers for other usecases, this means using an index.js, and adding more files in the reducers/ directory. So, I starded to change the name of reducers/index.js to reducers/Items.js, and added this the a new reducers/index.js :

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

import { selectItem, getSelectedItem } from './Items';

export default combineReducers({ selectItem, getSelectedItem })
```

I have this error :

```
Error: Reducer "getSelectedItem" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state. The initial state may not be undefined. If you don't want to set a value for this reducer, you can use null instead of undefined.
./src/reducers/index.js
> 5 | export default combineReducers({ selectItem, getSelectedItem })
```

From what I found on Google and StackOverFlow, I need to resolve this by having a default state returned by the reducer but this is already the case. Do you have any idea ? I'm a bit confused at this point.

Comment: your state is returned yes, but as it has no default value, the value returned from the reducer is still `undefined`, which causes the error at runtime `export const getSelectedItem = (state = 'some default value') => {
  return state
}` should sort that

Comment: I already tried, I have this error now : 
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {selectItem, getSelectedItem}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Well that's an entirely different question now (you cant render an object as if it were a child of a react component) You aren't showing that code for you render methods however so please open a different question

Comment: I need to open another question ? But all Redux related content is in the code I put above. The only lines that I use in render() functions from Redux are those ones :
ItemSelector.js : this.props.selectItem(itemId)
Item.js : {this.props.itemId}

Comment: Your original question which was redux related is fixed, and now you've asked a new question in the comments. This new question is related to the React rendering not redux, from which you have omitted most of the rendering code that will be causing your new issue. The only thing i can see that could cause it is if `this.props.itemId` was an object in which case to see its values you would need to `{JSON.stringify(this.props.itemId)}`